# 500 Unable to handle this request

Tags: php

Inside a method in my Model class, I include another PHP file. The code works until that included PHP file declares a class definition ie `class Test123 {}`.

The class name is unique. The only possible source of the issue that I could think of would be how I'm including a class within a class. However, I wasn't able to find information about this, so I assume it isn't a problem.

Any ideas?

//Inside of method inside of model class

`include "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/models/language.php";`

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber I run an ubuntu ec2 instance. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to locate my logs for PHP. I'l keep looking

Comment: The logs usually are in `/var/log`, and then in either httpd, apache, or nginx, depending on your web server and setup.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're right in assuming that you can't declare a class inside a class, which is what you're essentially doing by including it inside a class method.

Could you perhaps do something like this?

class.php:

```
<?php

include("otherclass.php");

class MyClass {
    public function run () {
        $otherClass = new OtherClass();
    }
}
```

otherclass.php:

```
<?php

class OtherClass {
}
```

index.php:

```
<?php

include("class.php");

$myClass = new MyClass();
$myClass->run();
```

Comment: I could do that. Although, this  include is only necessary for a single method in a very large class. I feel like it would be a inefficient to always include it when it mostly won't be used, what do you think?

Comment: Yes it is inefficient.  You should look at auto-loading, see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: This might also be useful: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/